# In memory key value store database of multi level

Tags: memcached, key-value, database, nosql

Is there any `in memory` `key value` datastore available of multiple level in which i can store the value again as a pair of key value? similar to a `JSON`

**Example :**

```
{
school1 : {classroom1 : ['student1','student2'], classroom2 : ['studentx','studenty']},
school2 : {classroom3 : ['student10','student20'], classroom4 : ['studentq','studentw']}
}
```

i wish to access classroom4 from school2 value without fetching the entire school2 value

Answer (score 1):

[Aerospike](http://www.aerospike.com/) is an [open source](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-server) key-value in-memory (persistence optional) clustered database. We refer to the "value" as a "Record" and each record may have one or more "Bins". When retrieving the record you can optionally specify a specific set of bins to retrieve over the network.

Aerospike supports many popular languages such as C, Go, Java, and Python. [Here is the Go API](https://godoc.org/github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go#Client.Get) to get a set of bins from a record (without actually transferring the entire record).

Aerospike is [ridiculously fast](http://highscalability.com/blog/2014/8/18/1-aerospike-server-x-1-amazon-ec2-instance-1-million-tps-for.html), recently achieving 1 Million transactions per second on a single C3.8xlarge Amazon EC2 instance.